# Is min(Comparator) equals to sorted(Comparator).findFirst()?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

With a `Stream<T>` and a `Comparator<? super T>`,

```
Stream<T> s;
Comparator<? super T> c;
```

is

```
s.sorted(c).findFirst();
```

<s>equals to</s> equivalent to

```
s.min(c);
```

?

Comment: Not equal, clearly, but could be said to be *equivalent*. The result of both expressions will be equal with enough memory and correctly implemented comparators. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1058609/134305

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt In mathematics words does not always means the same thing as in other disciplines. In programming we're talking about sameness when we're talking about the same object (`a == b`), and equal when they only compare equal (`a.equals(b)`). In this case term equal is probably the right term (or even same since the operation may work without copying the objects).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Logically, both code snippets return the same result. However, `sorted` takes more time and potentially more memory, because comparator-based sorting is O(n*log n) and needs O(n) space to avoid sorting in place, while searching for `min` is O(n), and needs O(1) space.